# POSTagger numbers classification

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've trained a model for a new language in POSTagger. Unfortunately the tagger missclassifies for big numbers (not written as words).

For instance:

> "There are 2 doctors." the 2 would be correctly classified as NUM.
>
> "The mayor embezzled 274556 dollars." the 274556 would be classified
> as VERB or NOUN.

The english models doesn't seem to be affected by this. How can I make sure that all numbers (not written as words) are classified as NUM?

**EDIT for latest .prop file**

```
    ## tagger training invoked at Thu May 07 19:42:46 CEST 2015 with arguments:
                   model = models/czech.tagger
                    arch = bidirectional, naacl2003unknowns, words(0,3),words(0,4),words(0,5), unicodeshapes(-2,2), allunicodeshapes(-2,2)
            wordFunction =
               trainFile = format=TSV,corpora/train.corpus
         closedClassTags =
 closedClassTagThreshold = 40
 curWordMinFeatureThresh = 2
                   debug = false
             debugPrefix =
            tagSeparator = /
                encoding = UTF-8
              iterations = 100
                    lang =
    learnClosedClassTags = false
        minFeatureThresh = 5
           openClassTags = ADJ ADV INTJ NOUN PROPN VERB
rareWordMinFeatureThresh = 10
          rareWordThresh = 5
                  search = owlqn2
                    sgml = false
            sigmaSquared = 0.5
                   regL1 = 1.0
```

The results on testFile:

```
Results on 10148 sentences and 174254 words, of which 12199 were unknown.
Total sentences right: 7983 (78.665747%); wrong: 2165 (21.334253%).
Total tags right: 171223 (98.260585%); wrong: 3031 (1.739415%).
Unknown words right: 11080 (90.827117%); wrong: 1119 (9.172883%).
```

Misclassification in tagging (roughly the same sentences as above):

```
Jsou    VERB
zde ADV
2   NUM
doktoři NOUN
.   PUNCT

Místní  ADJ
radní   NOUN
zpronevěřil VERB
2474556 NOUN
korun   NOUN
.   PUNCT
```

Comment: Can you post the `.properties` file used to train your tagger? I assume you missed the `unicodeshapes` command in your architecture specification.

Comment: You were right. I used bidirectional and naacl2003unknowns extractors. After I added unicodeshapes(-2,2) I have received much higher success rate on testFile, but unfortunately the very large numbers (such as in my original post) remains misclassified.

Comment: @JonGauthier I think the arch is not the issue. I used the german props (which classifies numbers correctly) and changed the tags & trainFile. The new model misclassifies again.
Is it possible the number classification for already implemented languages is defined in one of the Java source files?